# Separating disjoint sets of size $\aleph_1$ with Borel sets

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

**Question**: Is it consistent with ZFC that every pair of disjoint sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, both of size $\aleph_1$, can be separated by a Borel set?

This statement is clearly false under CH; take any non-Borel set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.  Then $|A| = |\mathbb{R}\setminus A| = \aleph_1$, but $A$ cannot be separated from its complement by any Borel set.  My guess is that it's always false, i.e. the answer to the above question is no.  A Hausdorff gap would seem to be a good way to get a counterexample, using Todorcevic's theorem on analytic gaps (see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm150/fm15016.pdf)), but I can't seem to get the right statement to come out. Maybe there's an easier counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example, if every set of reals of size $\omega_1$ is a Q-set (this means that every subset is relatively $G_{\delta}$), then you can separate them by a $G_{\delta}$.

Comment: Do you have an example of a model where this holds?

Comment: It follows from MA for sigma centered posets plus not CH.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this a minute ago!  And Asaf, this holds for example under MA.